# Bug in MySql and MariaDB when having an index on utf8mb4 data and the substring ü?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

When using a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  name VARCHAR(100),
  INDEX name_index (name)
) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```

And then inserting some data:

```
INSERT INTO test(name) VALUES('ü here is a  smiley');
INSERT INTO test(name) VALUES('ü no space smiley');
INSERT INTO test(name) VALUES('ü  space smiley');
INSERT INTO test(name) VALUES('ü without smiley');
```

This query fails:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE name LIKE ("ü%");
```

It ommits the 'ü no space smiley' row.

Here is a db-fiddle:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bR6Yx2PXPJdD7iSCLnW65Y/0

Interestingly, the result changes when one deletes the index. So without line 3 in the demo, it behaves as expected.

Is this a known bug?

I tried it in MySql 5.7, MySql 8.0 and MariaDB 10.3 - all showing the same behaviour.

Comment: Please can you comment this fiddle : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a8060099618ae0ed4e15b944a16eed1d

Comment: VBoka: Interesting that it does not show the bug on that page with MySql 5.7. When you switch it to MySql 8.0, it also shows the bug. Maybe it was introduced at some minor 5.7x version?

Comment: Common collation problem during compare.

Comment: Yes, I find it interesting. It also works on this page with 5.6 version and MariaDB 10.3

Comment: @no_gravity Formally the field with binary collation contains binary data, and string operator `LIKE` is not applicable to its value. Change collation of the field value before applying the operator (for example, `WHERE name COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci LIKE ("ü%")`), and the bug will disappear.

Comment: Akina: That would also match names starting with "u". As for utf8mb4_general_ci, "ü" equals "u". But that is not the desired behaviour.

Comment: If so perform byte compare. Especially since you need to match the template from the very beginning of the value.

Comment: One more. Define the field as VARBINARY and use `SELECT CAST(name as char) FROM test WHERE name LIKE ("ü%");`... [The binary Collation Compared to _bin Collations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-binary-collations.html).

Comment: Akina: From my tests, both (using BINARY or casting) will result in full table scans instead of using the index.

Here is an example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bR6Yx2PXPJdD7iSCLnW65Y/5

It scans all 8 rows. Without the BINARY only 4 rows.

Comment: 1) In my last approach the index should be used. 2) In recent server versions the virtual index will help too.

Comment: Akina:

Like this? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bR6Yx2PXPJdD7iSCLnW65Y/9

Interesting.

Comment: Please file a bug report. (bugs.mysql.com).  I checked several versions (5.5,.5.6,.5.7,.8.0..10.3..10.4); all work the same.

Answer (score 1):

After I have tried your code on another fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7
It worked for MySQL 5.7 and MySQL 5.6 and for MariaDB 10.3 but you have noticed it did not worked for **MySQL 8.0.**

I have changed your code for `CREATE TABLE` to this:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  name VARCHAR(100),
  INDEX name_index (name)
) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

And now it is ok :) [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9f154c11ac1e15ff782a61ace1ca1263)
Hope this helps.
Cheers!

For additional info check documentation here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-charsets.html

**UPDATE**

First solution does not work because u = ü In that case use this:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  name VARCHAR(100),
  INDEX name_index (name)
) CHARACTER SET gb18030 COLLATE gb18030_chinese_ci;
```

New [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=856cd1fec3ba6da970e1216c4901e592)

**UPDATE 2**

Well if this is the deal: "The character set needs to be utf8mb4" :) then without changing anything you can try this query:

```
SELECT name from test
where hex(name) like concat('%',hex('ü'),'%')
```

Here is a [DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bR6Yx2PXPJdD7iSCLnW65Y/17) in a new fiddle where you asked to be explained.
Cheers.

Comment: That would also match names starting with "u". As for utf8mb4_general_ci, "ü" equals "u". But that is not the desired behaviour.

Comment: VBoka: The character set needs to be utf8mb4.

Comment: VBoka: That does not use the index. It does a full table scan.

Comment: @no_gravity Sorry, I am not good with this fiddle and it says "Using where; Using index" so I thought all is ok... But As I see Akina's answer uses index. So you do have a solution?

Comment: VBoka: Not really. Using VARBINARY instead of VARCHAR magically prevents the bug, but makes dealing with the data pretty cumbersome.

Comment: Interesting , received a downvote = "the answer is not useful". Would be nice to know why ?

Comment: @no_gravity please can you tell me is this ok for you. If yes, I will update my answer: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bR6Yx2PXPJdD7iSCLnW65Y/22